# how to find column that has the highest value for the first row

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find the column that produces the highest value in a single row, I am using

```
colnames(df)[which.max(df[[,1]])]
```

however R gives me the following error

```
Error in [[.data.frame`(df, , 1) : 
  argument "..1" is missing, with no default
```

I don't really understand what the error means so any help would be appreciated

Comment: `,1` selects the first column, I think you want the first row. Further, `[[` doesn't take empty arguments like `[` does, I think you want `colnames(df)[which.max(df[1,])]`.

Comment: Thank you for the help :) However I'm still having an issue as all I get back from R now is 'NA', do you know why this could be?

Comment: No, and without sample data, there is no way we can know for certain. Perhaps you can [edit] your question and post the output from `dput(head(df))` into a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

Comment: Possible causes: non-numbers in the first row; `NA`s in the first row; perhaps a few other things. There are workarounds and techniques for each of those, I don't want to throw the most-resilient-ever expression since much of it may not be necessary with your real data.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense my column names are letters rather than numbers - how would i go about getting this to work with letters then

Comment: Post `dput(head(df))` so we can help with that.

Comment: It has nothing to do with numbers in the columns' _names_, it may be about non-numeric data in the columns' _values_. (All `data.frame` column names are strings. All. Even some that look like numbers are strings. Always.)

Comment: Try `names(which.max(Filter(is.numeric, df)[1,]))`. It only considers numbers and returns the name of the column with the max value in row 1.